# Should I abbreviate word starting with “kn” as “K” or “N”?

Tags: abbreviations, silent-letters

Imagine you're abbreviating a title that has a *kn*-word in it (e.g. *Should Know*).
What is the preferred way? Is it **SK** or **SN**?

Comment: The Gnostic Knights of Pneumatic Knowledge, aka the **NNNN**.

Comment: In chess notation, "Knight" is abbreviated "N", but that is only because "King" is abbreviated "K".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Abbreviations are usually based on the first letters of the words they represent, and I would choose "SK" in this case (additionally "SN" is a well-known abbreviation for "Serial Number" across many different industries, so it's probably a good one to avoid when possible as well).

Consider also the word "Herbs," a word for which some people don't pronounce the letter "H" -- regardless of how this word is pronounced, an abbreviation would normally include the letter "H" to represent it (using the letter "E" would be confusing).

Answer (score 4):

**Kn** starting a word would become **K**, by convention. For instance, *JSYK* is common shorthand for *Just so you know*.

Comment: Or _IDK_, _AFAIK_, etc. quite a few of these out there.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, *know* is often abbreviated to *K*.

More generally, both phonetic and spelling-based abbreviations exist.

Comment: Can you give some examples of phonetic abbreviations? I can't think of any at all…

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet *N* for *Knight* (chess) skips a silent letter while *XML* for *Extensible Markup Language* uses the name of the letter *X* to represent the /ks/ sound of *extensible*. Much rarer than just the letter being used, though.

Comment: Ah yes. X is a good example. That one seems to be quite common, even, initial /eks/ being represented by X rather than E.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: "X" is funny, since it can sometimes represent various sequences of letters.  Receive/transmit abbreviates to rx/tx, but transmit shortens to xmit (and, less often, transducer is xducer, etc.)  None of those are phonetic; I'm not quite sure where they came from.

Comment: @supercat They derive from the etymology of the words: _trans-_ means ‘across’, and _X_ is of course also a cross. The same notional use is found in Spanish, where _por_ (‘through, via, across’) is often written _x_ in textspeak, as in _xk_ (= _porque_ ‘because’ or _¿por qué?_ ‘why?’).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: That makes sense, though I'd never thought of "a cross" as "across".  Was a famous engineer somewhere also a punster?

Comment: @supercat _Across_ is really from Old French _a croix_ or _en croix_, meaning just ‘on a cross’—the current meaning came later as a reinterpretation of the word. But the notion that the shape of a cross is somehow related to moving from one end of something to the other is strangely pervasive in European languages (I say strangely—it probably originated in Mediaeval Latin or Old French and spread from there). We do say that we cross something from one end to the other, too, when we go across it.

Answer (score 0):

Abbreviations could be with the pronunciation of the word, for example, 'n' for 'and', and 'k' for 'okay'. Other such abbreviations can be seen [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMS_language#Vocabulary).

It really depends where you are. If you are texting, then maybe 'N', if you are putting it as a message, probably either, if you are putting it as the name of something, probably 'K'.